# One function is running for all div containing same class. How can i get rid of it?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, function

I am trying to make a galley for my web page. I want to make that when some one click on my images two icon will be came from the down. I also made the design. but when i give a function to my js. the problem is that when i click on a image, all of my image's icon shows up. it can b solved by giving individual class name to every image and individual function for every images. But that is so long for me. Can anyone help me?

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  $(".cus_column").click(function(){
    $(".respn_btn").toggleClass("toggle");
  });
  
});
```

```css
.work_wrapper{
  padding:2% 1%;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  text-align:center;
}
.work_wrapper > .cus_column{
  width:33%;
  height:40vh;
  display:inline-block;
  background:#ddd;
  margin-bottom:0.2%;
  position:relative;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.work_wrapper > .cus_column > .overlay{
  position:absolute;
  background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}
.work_wrapper > .cus_column > img{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
.work_wrapper > .cus_column > .hidden_box{
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  transform:translateY(-50%);
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:15vh;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.respn_btn{
  margin-right:4%;
  margin-top:35%;
  transition:0.5s all ease;
}
.work_wrapper > .cus_column > .hidden_box > a:last-child{
  transition:1s all ease;
}
.work_wrapper > .cus_column > .hidden_box > a > img{
  width:3vw;
}
.toggle.respn_btn{
  margin-top:0% !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="work_wrapper">
    <div class="cus_column">
      <div class="overlay"></div>
      <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1pGasu0J_xLwt3aLFVwrkQwcZ-yTywlJf" />
      <div class="hidden_box">
        <a href="#" class="respn_btn">
          <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1nWohtvmAy4EEa9JbqtvDHHBLxx0Jx7R1" />
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="respn_btn">
          <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1PNWI_Lp7i4oZOTR83WWZSJ5P5UKFIcv3" />
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cus_column">
      <div class="overlay"></div>
      <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1EUHgHbDtjyU2MTC69_cFgr3djM4UCfnS" />
      <div class="hidden_box">
        <a href="#" class="respn_btn">
          <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1nWohtvmAy4EEa9JbqtvDHHBLxx0Jx7R1" />
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="respn_btn">
          <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1PNWI_Lp7i4oZOTR83WWZSJ5P5UKFIcv3" />
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add a reference of the click event target (`this`):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  $(".cus_column").click(function(){
    $(this).find(".respn_btn").toggleClass("toggle");
  });
  
});
```

```css
.work_wrapper{
  padding:2% 1%;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  text-align:center;
}
.work_wrapper > .cus_column{
  width:33%;
  height:40vh;
  display:inline-block;
  background:#ddd;
  margin-bottom:0.2%;
  position:relative;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.work_wrapper > .cus_column > .overlay{
  position:absolute;
  background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}
.work_wrapper > .cus_column > img{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
.work_wrapper > .cus_column > .hidden_box{
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  transform:translateY(-50%);
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:15vh;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.respn_btn{
  margin-right:4%;
  margin-top:35%;
  transition:0.5s all ease;
}
.work_wrapper > .cus_column > .hidden_box > a:last-child{
  transition:1s all ease;
}
.work_wrapper > .cus_column > .hidden_box > a > img{
  width:3vw;
}
.toggle.respn_btn{
  margin-top:0% !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="work_wrapper">
    <div class="cus_column">
      <div class="overlay"></div>
      <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1pGasu0J_xLwt3aLFVwrkQwcZ-yTywlJf" />
      <div class="hidden_box">
        <a href="#" class="respn_btn">
          <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1nWohtvmAy4EEa9JbqtvDHHBLxx0Jx7R1" />
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="respn_btn">
          <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1PNWI_Lp7i4oZOTR83WWZSJ5P5UKFIcv3" />
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cus_column">
      <div class="overlay"></div>
      <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1EUHgHbDtjyU2MTC69_cFgr3djM4UCfnS" />
      <div class="hidden_box">
        <a href="#" class="respn_btn">
          <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1nWohtvmAy4EEa9JbqtvDHHBLxx0Jx7R1" />
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="respn_btn">
          <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1PNWI_Lp7i4oZOTR83WWZSJ5P5UKFIcv3" />
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: So simple! Tnx a lot @Greedo